# graph - What are the differences between Embedded and Topological in Graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, topology

In [Algorithm Design Manual](http://www.algorist.com/), page 178 describes some properties of Graph, and one of them is embedded and Topological:

> Embedded vs. Topological
>
> A graph is embedded if the vertices and
> edges are assigned geometric positions. Thus, any drawing of a graph
> is an embedding, which may or may not have algorithmic significance.
>
> Occasionally, the structure of a graph is completely defined by the
> geometry of its embedding. For example, if we are given a collection
> of points in the plane, and seek the minimum cost tour visiting all of
> them (i.e., the traveling salesman problem), the underlying topology
> is the complete graph connecting each pair of vertices. The weights
> are typically defined by the Euclidean distance between each pair of
> points.
>
> Grids of points are another example of topology from geometry.
> Many problems on an n × m grid involve walking between neighboring
> points, so the edges are implicitly defined from the geometry.

I quite don't understand it:

1. First of all, what exactly does `embedded` mean here? As long as the vertices have their own geometric positions, then can I call the graph embedded?
2. What does `any drawing of a graph is an embedding` mean? Does it mean what I said in point 1?
3. What does `Topological` mean? I don't think it is explained in this description.
4. The examples in this description really confused me a lot. Could someone please use simplest words to let me understand these two terms for graph?
5. **Is it really important to get these two term understood?**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I remind you that a graph is just a set of vertices and a set of edges defined on them, so the vertices don't have a geometric position of their own. A drawing of a graph is called an embedding, a drawn graph is called embedded.
2. It means that any way of drawing a graph is called an embedding of that graph.
3. A topological graph is a graph whose vertices and edges are points and arcs, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to msj's answer.

Graph = `G(V, E)`, where `V` is set of vertex and and `E` is set pair of vertices from V. This is definition of graph as per Skiena. Note how there is no mention of how this graph visually appear (i.e no mention of its topology).

Example (note that it doesn't define where `a`, `b` are located in say X,Y coordinate system)

`V = { a, b, c, d, e, f }` and `E = { (a,b), (b,c), (a,e) }`

To 'draw' a graph you assign it geometric positions e.g. in X,Y coordinate systems.

```
|
|           b (2,3)
|   a(1,2)
|
|
|____________________________
 Fig 1
```

Fig 1 is simply an embedding where we are drawing vertex pairs specified in `E`

Difference between embedded and topological graph is how does the "topology" comes to be. In any "embedding" you manually assign geometric locations as explained above, but in topological graph you define a "rule" based on which topology of a graph defines itself. e.g. you specify a `G(V,E)` and define a rule, say "visit each node exactly once" defines the topology which is called "complete graph".

Answer (score 1):

A topological graph and an embedded graph are two concepts in graph theory that are related but distinct. Understanding their differences involves considering how they represent relationships and how they are visualized.

1. **Topological Graph**:

   - A topological graph focuses on the connections between nodes (vertices) and edges without considering the geometric specifics of those edges and vertices.
   - In a topological graph, the exact positions of vertices and the paths of edges are not important. What matters is how the vertices are connected by the edges.
   - This kind of graph is used to study properties and features that are invariant under topological transformations, such as connectivity and planarity.
   - An example of a topological graph is a subway map, where stations are connected by lines representing routes. The physical distances and locations of the stations are not represented accurately.
2. **Embedded Graph**:

   - An embedded graph, on the other hand, is a graph in which the specific geometric positions of vertices and the paths of edges are fixed and significant.
   - This type of graph is used when the exact spatial representation of the graph is crucial. The embedding can be in a plane (planar embedding) or in higher-dimensional spaces.
   - In an embedded graph, properties like the length of edges, angles between edges, and the spatial arrangement of vertices are important and are taken into consideration.
   - A real-world map with accurately plotted cities (vertices) and roads (edges) is an example of an embedded graph, where the actual geographical positions and distances are crucial.

In summary, the key difference lies in how these graphs treat the geometric aspects of vertices and edges: topological graphs abstract away from the geometric details, focusing solely on the connections, while embedded graphs incorporate the precise geometric positions and paths into their structure.

Answer (score 0):

Skiena uses geographical friendship graph as an example for embedded graph because each vertex is associated with a geographical point in this world where friends live.

Excerpt from the book - 
Do my friends live near me? – Social networks are not divorced from geography. Many of your friends are your friends only because they happen to live near you (e.g., neighbors) or used to live near you (e.g., college roommates).

Thus, a full understanding of social networks requires an embedded graph, where each vertex is associated with the point in this world where they live. This geographic information may not be explicitly encoded, but the fact that the graph is inherently embedded in the plane shapes our interpretation of any analysis.